# Execute mouse macro without disturbing the physical mouse?

Tags: windows-10, macros, mouse-click

I have used tinytask to execute simple macro involving clicking at a point. But when I start the macro, it takes my physical mouse. I want to be able to run the macro in the background and continue working with mouse.

Is there a macro which will not disturb the physical mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out :) 
I downloaded [TeamPlayer 2.0.10](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/install-multiple-mouse-and-keyboard-on-one-computer/) which is free for non-commercial use. Once installed and opened, it automatically detects the mice. One is the touchpad of my laptop and other is the external mouse. I used tinytask to record with the touchpad mouse pointer and it works! I can now use the physical mouse to do other things while the macro is running in the side.